# Multipliers in trace spaces

Tags: reference-request, sobolev-spaces

I need a reference for the following fact. Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ be an open domain with $C^{1,1}$ boundary (maybe, less regularity is needed). Let $H^{1/2}(\Gamma)$ be the trace space of $H^1(\Omega)$. Then, the multiplication with a function $\theta \in C^{0,1}(\Gamma)$ is a bounded, linear operator in $H^{1/2}(\Gamma)$.

I think it can be easily proved by using extensions of the functions from $\Gamma$ to $\Omega$, but I think, there should be a nice reference somewhere.

Comment: This is true for $H^{1/2}(B)$ where $B$ ithe unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$, hence, by using charts and a partition of unit, you can conclude it for $H^{1/2}(\Gamma)$. This kind of solution is useful for you? I dont know any reference...

Comment: If my calculations are right, this is also true for $\theta\in C^{0,1/2}(\Gamma)$ and you can take $\Omega$ with $C^{0,1}$ boundary.

Comment: @Tomás: Thank you for your answer. Can you show your calculation? My estimate needs $\theta \in C^{0,1/2+\varepsilon}(\Gamma)$ in the case $n = 3$.

Comment: I would try to find it in [Sobolev multipliers](http://books.google.com/books?id=QN8uP6Mn0yQC), but I don't have access to the book (and it's too voluminous for Google Books preview to be very helpful). Failing that, I'd argue by extension: Lipschitz functions extend to Lipschitz functions on $\Omega$, which are obviously multipliers on $H^1$.

Comment: That's funny. I was writing the calculations for you and I saw an error in it. In fact they also need $\theta \in C^{0,1/2+\epsilon}$. But in my calculations this is necessary for all $n$. For $n\neq 3$, does $\theta\in C^{0,1/2}$ is sufficient?

Comment: Maybe this might help too: http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=7&ved=0CGoQFjAG&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mai.liu.se%2F~vlmaz%2Fpdf%2Fweighted.pdf&ei=euPKUZbHOIbZ0QH41IBo&usg=AFQjCNGdfA4X263-mS3vXdaB650mstudSA&sig2=AZcqY8WXJWPMjFQUvaCsog

Comment: I checked my "proof" and I also need $C^{0,1/2+\varepsilon}(\Gamma)$ in all dimensions.